# rdlc report not working on Azure Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reportviewer

I am trying to run a website on Windows Azure that uses the ReportViewer control, but when I run the website, I get the below error.

I only have FTP access to the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly telling you a DLL or one of its dependencies is missing.

You need to find which one is NOT being deployed to Azure.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx) are the dependencies for that report viewer, have a look at each one's properties in the project to make sure they are set to copy local.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg430128.aspx) is a tutorial on using that control in Azure.

Comment: yes i know that but i should clear in my question I have only ftp not viewer for azure